# ¿ Como cambiar el color de varias listas desplegables con css?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy tratando de crear un menú lateral en que tengo varias listas desplegables.

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap pero aún necesito aprender más. Cuando paso el ratón por los diferentes elementos del menú, estos van cambiando de color.

Mi idea es que cada una de las listas sean de un color diferente, pero sigan mostrando el color blanco cuando paso el cursor por encima, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio, conseguí que la lista se mostrara de un color diferente, como se ve en la captura de pantalla...

[image]

...pero cuando despliego la lista, esta no se muestra del color que quiero.

[image]

Además, al desplegar la lista, se pierde el color que tengo puesto.
Ya que parto de una pequeña plantilla, la muestro el código al completo, no se como manejar
He buscado y leído documentación, pero aún no entiendo el funcionamiento de css y no se como aplicar a cada una de las listas un color diferente incluso cuando están desplegadas.
¿ Como puedo conseguir esto ?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

  const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      nav = document.getElementById(navId),
      bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
      headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // show navbar
        nav.classList.toggle('show')
        // change icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        // add padding to body
        bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
        // add padding to header
        headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }

  showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

  /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')

  function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))

  // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
   
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
    display: inline-block;
   
}
button {
    padding-top: 0rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 0rem!important;
}

.btn-outline-danger {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.btn-outline-success {
    padding: 5px;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.tituloPanel {
    text-align: center;
}

.categoriasColor{
    background: rgb(4, 146, 33);
}

.productosColor {
    background: rgb(144, 22, 22);
}
.alertasColor {
  background: rgb(224, 22, 211);
}
.logo {
    align-items: center;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}
/* Logo*/
.sidebar-header img {
 
    padding: 10px 30px 10px;
 }

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Menu Lateral</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/sidebarCuston.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Sidebar  -->
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
          <img src="./img/512X512.png" class="rounded-circle" alt="logo">
          <h3 class="tituloPanel"> Panel Administrador </h3>
          <strong>PA</strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <li class="active usuarioscolor">
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="sidebaruser dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              Usuarios
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Nuevo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Lista</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Buscar</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="categoriasColor">
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
              Categorias
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Lista</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Buscar</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="productosColor">
            <a href="#pageProductos" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-cubes"></i>
              Productos
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageProductos">
              <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
              <a href="#">Lista</a>
              <a href="#">Por Categoria</a>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
              Detalles
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="alertasColor">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
              Alertas
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
              FAQ
            </a>
          </li>
      </nav>
      <!-- Nav Bar  -->
      <div id="content">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
              <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
              <span></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Mi Cuenta</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Salir</button>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
          $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="./js/ajax.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más simple es que heredes la propiedad `background` del padre a sus hijos

```
nav > ul > li  * {
 background: inherit !important;
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

Para añadir el fondo blanco cuando se pose el mouse arriba

```
nav > ul > li  a:hover {
 background: white !important;
 color:#47748b !important;
}
```

Para añadir el fondo blanco, a TODA la sección, cuando se pose el mouse arriba

```
nav > ul > li:hover {
 background: white !important;
 color:#47748b !important;
}
```

De esta manera no hay que realizar más cambios

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

  const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      nav = document.getElementById(navId),
      bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
      headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // show navbar
        nav.classList.toggle('show')
        // change icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        // add padding to body
        bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
        // add padding to header
        headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }

  showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

  /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')

  function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))

  // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

nav > ul > li  * {
 background: inherit !important;
 color: inherit !important;
 transition: background 0.8s;
}

nav > ul > li a:hover {
 background: white !important;
 color:#47748b !important;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
   
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
    display: inline-block;
   
}
button {
    padding-top: 0rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 0rem!important;
}

.btn-outline-danger {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.btn-outline-success {
    padding: 5px;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.tituloPanel {
    text-align: center;
}

.categoriasColor{
    background: rgb(4, 146, 33);
}

.productosColor {
    background: rgb(144, 22, 22);
}
.alertasColor {
  background: rgb(224, 22, 211);
}
.logo {
    align-items: center;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}
/* Logo*/
.sidebar-header img {
 
    padding: 10px 30px 10px;
 }

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Menu Lateral</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/sidebarCuston.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Sidebar  -->
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
          <img src="./img/512X512.png" class="rounded-circle" alt="logo">
          <h3 class="tituloPanel"> Panel Administrador </h3>
          <strong>PA</strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <li class="active usuarioscolor">
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="sidebaruser dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              Usuarios
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Nuevo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Lista</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Buscar</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="categoriasColor">
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
              Categorias
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Lista</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Buscar</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="productosColor">
            <a href="#pageProductos" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-cubes"></i>
              Productos
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageProductos">
              <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
              <a href="#">Lista</a>
              <a href="#">Por Categoria</a>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
              Detalles
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="alertasColor">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
              Alertas
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
              FAQ
            </a>
          </li>
      </nav>
      <!-- Nav Bar  -->
      <div id="content">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
              <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
              <span></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Mi Cuenta</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Salir</button>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
          $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="./js/ajax.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por supuesto tu respuesta funciona @Yussef, pero tengo solo tengo una duda, me gustaría que cada sección sea de fondo blanco cuando paso el raton, ya estaba en la pregunta pero ahora añadi una imagen para que quede más claro. Ahora, al pasar el raton, no se ve el texto de las lista ya que es del mismo color que el fondo, es por ello que en principio queria cambiar el fondo completo. ¿se puede hacer con css o es necesario js ?

Comment: @unity-student Ahí edite el asunto, verifícalo y recuerda que si te parece puedes dar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

sé que este comentario es un poco largo pero te pongo lo esencial para que aprendas a usar **css**.
El **css** funciona por elementos, clases o id:
Los elementos son los **div, body, nav**, o sea las etiquetas que pones en **html**; estas se llaman en **css** por su mismo nombre pero al llamarlas generalizas todas las etiquetas con ese nombre por ejemplo:
 **div: {
}**
Luego están las **clases** que son las que pones en **html** dentro de las etiquetas con **class="identificador"**, estas se llaman en **css** por el identificador que pusiste dentro de **class=""** pero agregandole delante un punto y solo modificarán la etiqueta que tenga esa clase por ejemplo: 
**.indentificador: {
}**
Después están las **id** que son las que pones en **html** dentro de las etiquetas con **id="identificador"**, estas se llaman en **css** por el identificador como las clases pero con la diferencia de que en vez de un punto va un **#** y solo modifican la etiqueta que tenga esa id por ejemplo: 
**#identificador: {
}**
Para agregarle un fondo a un **div** puedes usar una **clase** o un **id** de la siguiente forma:

```
/*Como clase*/
.fondo {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF
}

/*Como id*/
#fondo {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Aquí te dejo el enlace de una página para que saques los colores que quieras por si no tienes una aún.
https://htmlcolorcodes.com/es/
En caso de que tengas un elemento con varios elementos dentro del mismo tipo puedes ponerle un solo identificador al elemento padre y luego al elemento hijo llamarlo en **css** con **:nth-child(numero de hijo)** de la siguiente forma:

**En html**

```
<ul id="lista" class="lista">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li><a href="#">WhatsApp</></li>
</ul>
```

**En css**

```
/*Como clase*/
.lista li:nth-child(1) {
    background: #00FFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.lista li:nth-child(2) {
    background: #00FF00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.lista li:nth-child(3) {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.lista li a: {
    /*Para que no salga la linea debajo del enlace*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Como id*/
#lista li:nth-child(1) {
    background: #00FFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#lista li:nth-child(2) {
    background: #00FF00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#lista li:nth-child(3) {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#lista li a: {
    /*Para que no salga la linea debajo del enlace*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

En caso de que quieras pintar intercalado puedes usar **:nth-child(even)** y **:nth-child(odd)** por ejemplo:

```
/*Como clase*/
.lista li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #00FFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.lista li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #00FF00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Como id*/
#lista li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #00FFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#lista li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #00FF00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Te aconsejo que vayas probando con las funciones que te da el css para que vayas viendo para que sirve cada cosa y que hacer con ellas. Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: he tenido un confusión con la respuesta. Gracias por tu explicación, no vengo en busca de soluciones si no en busca de sabiduría  Esta muy bien detallado, unicamente tendre que hacer pruebas, aunque la respuesta de @Yussef funciona, y tu explicación esta muy bien. solo tengo que estudiarlo y tratar de aplicarlo a mi código y por supuesto buscar documentación para tratar de asimilar y aprender los conceptos que me cuentas. Gracias